# Проверка отображения слоя

Tags: objective-c

Добрый вечер!

Имеется массив слоев (layer), и в цикле я их добавляю в качестве `subLayer` к моему `ViewController'у` данной командой: `[self.view.layer addSublayer:[array objectAtIndex:i]]`. Тут никаких проблем.

Интересует следующий вопрос: как отловить момент отображения этих слоев? Т.к. цикл проходит быстрее, чем отображаются слои, а мне обязательно нужно отловить время отображения этих самых слоев для пользователя.

Comment: @Beginnerrr, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону:

`- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer`

Comment: К сожалению, это немного не то, но именно когда я глядел данную сторону, я нашел более менее рабочий для себя костыль (а может, и не костыль) -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews, так что огромное Вам спасибо, углублюсь на выходных конкретно в layer'ы, и если мое текущее решение будет совсем неверным, отпишу здесь.